# To go Or in going

Tags: grammar

There was a question in a competitive exam and it was like this.

> When the teachers are on strike and a notice to this effect is pasted on the gate there is no sense **to go** there.

The question was asked to find out which part of the sentence has an error.
The answer is "replace **to go** by **in going**".

> When the teachers are on strike and a notice to this effect is pasted on the gate there is no sense ***in going*** there.

Can anybody explain the answer elaborately?

Comment: *On this affect* is strange too.

Comment: Sorry...My mistake..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [licensing](/questions/tagged/licensing) issue. As several questions on that tag will tell you (just click on the button), each verb and verbal idiom<sup>†</sup>  licenses distinct sorts of complement.

*BE no sense* takes a preposition—usually *in*, but occasionally you will encounter *to*—and the preposition takes a gerund clause as its object. The subject of the clause may be expressed with either a possessive or an objective NP.

> There is no sense in going there.
>   There is no sense in our going there.
>   There is no sense in us going there.

*MAKE no sense* takes a *to*-infinitive clause. If the subject is expressed the clause must be introduced with the *complementizer/subordinator* *for*, and a pronominal subject is cast in the objective case:

> It makes no sense to go there.
>   It makes no sense for us to go there.

---

<sup>†</sup> and many adjectives, too